# How to submit multiple queries in Google BigQuery Composer and Cloud Shell

Tags: google-bigquery

Just a simple question, please don't tell me that submitting multiple queries is not supported in Query Composer and Google Cloud Shell.

When I submit two statements(for example drop table statements delimited by ";"), it tells me that the drop word on the next line is unexpected.

Comment: `please don't tell me that submitting multiple queries is not supported` - this really makes answering not possible because it is the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that there are no ways to execute multiple queries in either the BigQuery Composer or the the Google Cloud Shell. However, 1 workaround that I have found is to create a local text file in Cloud Shell which stores the queries, delimited by ";". And then set the IFS (Internal Field Separator) to ";" so that I can use a for loop to loop through the file and execute the queries one by one.
Example:

queries.txt

```
select 1+2;
select 2+3;
select 3+4;
```

Cloud Shell command

```
IFS=";"
alias bqn="bq query --nouse_legacy_sql"
for q in $(<"queries.txt");　do bqn $q; done;
```

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery now has support for multi-statement execution. Check out the [scripting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting). Copying the example:

```sql
-- Declare a variable to hold names as an array.
DECLARE top_names ARRAY<STRING>;
-- Build an array of the top 100 names from the year 2017.
SET top_names = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(name ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 100)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data`.usa_names.usa_1910_current
  WHERE year = 2017
);
-- Which names appear as words in Shakespeare's plays?
SELECT
  name AS shakespeare_name
FROM UNNEST(top_names) AS name
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT word
  FROM `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery is an SQL like language and not all implementations of a mainstream SQL language will be directly compatible with BigQuery.

That being said, there are many ways to workaround. If you are creating table to [materialize](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#carefully_consider_materializing_large_result_sets) data in order to have better Query performance and limit the [cost of storing data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#pricing_summary) in BigQuery, you can set a [expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#creating_a_dataset) date on the temporary table.

This is the command with the expiration date flag:

```
bq --location=[LOCATION] mk --dataset --default_table_expiration [INTEGER] --description [DESCRIPTION] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET]
```